# Sequelize, how to update an associated model on another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How do I update a model with new associations in Sequelize? The model is many-to-many with a join table. I tried this:

```
app.patch('/api/team/:id/newplayers', function(request, response){
  const players = request.body.players
  db.teams.findOne({
    where: {id: request.params.id},
    include: [{model: db.players}, {model: db.tournaments}]
  }).then(team => {
    return team.updateAttributes(players).then(updatedTeam => {
      response.json(updatedTeam)
    })
  })
})
```

But that doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors either. It just doesn't update "players".

Do I have to mess with the join table directly? I thought Sequelize would do a lot of that for you? My brain hurts :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to delete all the old players and add new ones. Or more complex, you have to compare the old ones with the new ones. Insert which is not there/ edit which is already there.

The simplest way is delete all the old ones and add new ones. Something like.

```
.then(team => {
    return db.players.destroy({ 
        where: { id: team.players.map(player => player.id) }
    }).then(() => team)
}).then(team => {
    // should add team id to the players object
    return db.players.bulkCreate(players).then(updatedTeam => {
      response.json(updatedTeam)
    })
  })
```